# Question about "The portrait utilizes a palette of..."

Tags: meaning, word-choice, animacy

Is this sentence correct?

> The portrait utilizes a palette of grays, blacks and blues.

Doesn’t it sound like the portrait painted itself? Shouldn’t it be "The artist utilized a palette of grays, blacks and blues."

Comment: Consider also "This pen/book writes/reads well." The pen isn't writing, and the book isn't reading; the pen is being written with, and the book read (by someone).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your sentence is correct. It is a figure of speech called ***[personification](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02IPALFjA4nXX9IL2_jT9ChW-5sdQ%3A1609180879694&ei=zybqX9PsKeCI1fAP7cSQQA&q=personification+meaning&oq=personnifica&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgBMgoIABCxAxDJAxAKMgcIABCxAxAKMgcIABCxAxAKMgcIABCxAxAKMgIIADIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjIECAAQCjoECCMQJzoFCAAQkQI6BQguEJECOggILhCxAxCDAToFCAAQsQM6CAgAELEDEIMBOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoTCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQyQMQQxCTAjoECAAQQzoHCAAQsQMQQzoFCC4QsQM6CwguELEDEMcBEK8BOggIABDJAxCRAjoKCC4QxwEQrwEQQzoJCCMQJxBGEPkBOgoIABCxAxAUEIcCOgQILhBDOggIABCxAxDJAzoICC4QxwEQrwE6CAguEMcBEKMCOgoIABCxAxCDARAKUMfjAVj--QFgwI8CaAFwAXgAgAGWAYgB-wiSAQQxMC4zmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab)*** which is commonly used. Look at [this example](https://www.theartstory.org/artist/da-vinci-leonardo/artworks/):

> ***The picture utilizes a pyramidal arrangement*** common of High Renaissance artists, although Leonardo's perfection of anatomical movement and fluidity elevates the figures with a sense of realistic motion.

However, the expression itself is rarely used, as [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20picture%20utilizes%2C%20the%20artist%20utilizes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20artist%20utilizes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20artist%20utilizes%3B%2Cc0) finds no instances of it in written texts.

Note: It can be *utilizes* (AmE) or *utilises* (BrE).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediopassive_voice

Comment: @LPH: very interesting link! Thank you. However,  "utilizes" looks very active here.

Comment: It is not the portrait that is "utilized" in fact, you see. It is just used as a subject "instead of" the artist that painted it.

Comment: (BrE also utilise) https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/utilize?q=utilize

Comment: "Note: It can be utilizes (AmE) or utilises (BrE)." Or "uses".

Comment: @Acccumulation: Yes, correct. I did not want to change the particular context given by the OP. And as LPH indicated, [BrE accepts both "utilize" and "utilise"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=utilize%2C+utilise&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) (in fact the variant with "z" prevails).